# How to remove Icons from the new Dropbox App Mac?

Tags: mac, icon, dropbox

Until the new release of Dropbox, you could rename the icon resources in the Dropbox.app (Mac version). But this doesn’t work anymore with the new Dropbox release.

Is there anybody who figured out yet, how you can remove these irritating big green checkmarks that overlay everything else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot,

Gary

Comment: This should help your issue https://superuser.com/questions/1193399/how-to-stop-showing-the-dropbox-green-checkmarks-across-every-photo Regards, Udhy